# any site redirects me to another website on google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I dont know if this is a malicious website,I tested it in 2 site scans but they said its safe.But I dont believe in that.

Here's the sites link:
`http://err.quicksearch.website/error.aspx` (those words are turkish saying that chrome needs to update manually)

I cant post the error.aspx,because of it contains some links to another websites and I  dont have any reputation.
Please say it fast,and please tell me if its a malware how I can remove it.

Comment: A [whois](https://who.is/whois/https://err.quicksearch.website/error.aspx) lookup provides nothing more useful than the knowledge that the site only got registered on the 17th and it's owner is hiding behind an anonymizing service.  I'm suspicious, but it's not damning evidence by any means.

Comment: It's an malware. http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-search-quick-com-virus/  scan with Anti-malware (from Malwarebytes for example)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Answer (score 1):

If you find something weird with your browser, take a look into your installed plugins `chrome://plugins` and extensions `chrome://extensions`

malwares can take over your chrome browser through extensions and plugins. If you find any unwanted or recently installed (which you haven't installed yourself) simply click on the trash icon next to the extension or click on disable on the plugin.

After doing, this I recommend an antivirus search and a look at your uninstaller's recently installed programs.

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing the same problem since yesterday evening. After some research on the Net, I decided to switch to Google's DNS Servers, following [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) link.

So far, I have not faced the problem. Just wanted to share, in case it helps someone.